# TypeError: 'ReplyKeyboardMarkup' object is not callable telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет.
Есть у меня такая часть функции в телеботе.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Игры':

            markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            markup("GTA V Premium","RDR 2", "Watch Dogs 2") #bug
            markup.row("Назад в меню")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Какую игру вы хотите преобрести?:\n1. GTA V Premium\n2. Red Dead Redemtion 2\n3. Watch Dogs 2 (Deluxe)',reply_markup=markup)

            harlos = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            harlos_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Еще продукты",callback_data="next1")
            harlos.add(harlos_button)
            opt_buttons = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            opt_buttons.row("Ghostrunner", "Cyberpunk 2077")
            opt_buttons.row("Обратно""Назад в меню")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"Хорошо, вот второй список\nЧто здесь ты хочешь преобрести?:\n1.Ghostrunner - {ghostrunner_price} рублей\n2. Cyberpunk 2077 - {ghostrunner_price} рублей",reply_markup=harlos_button)
    elif message.text == "Назад в меню":
        info(message)
    elif message.text == "GTA V Premium":

        markup111 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        mm = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да!✅",callback_data="yes")
        #mm2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет❌",callback_data='no')
        markup111.add(mm)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"Хороший выбор! GTA V Premium стоит {gtav_price} рублей. Перейдем к оплате?",reply_markup = markup111)
```

При срабатывании этой части функции, у меня ошибка на 4 строке.
Сама ошибка:

```
markup("GTA V Premium","RDR 2", "Watch Dogs 2") #bug
TypeError: 'ReplyKeyboardMarkup' object is not callable
```

Как можно пофиксить.
Часть этого кода писал не я, поэтому не обессудьте за названия переменных, в ближайшее время исправлю названия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно добавляете кнопки в клавиатуру, должно быть так:

```
markup.add("GTA V Premium")
markup.add("RDR 2")
markup.add("Watch Dogs 2")
```